# All pairs of pairs python

Tags: python

Given a  list `l=range(n)`, how can I iterate over all distinct pairs of distinct pairs from that list.

For example, if `l = [0,1,2,3]` I would like `[((0,1), (0,2)),((0,1),(0,3)), ((0,1),(1,2)), ((0,1), (1,3)),((0,1), (2,3)), ((0,2), (0,3)), ((0,2),(1,2)),((0,2),(1,3)),((0,2),(2,3))...`

Comment: @wheaties I tried playing with itertools but I couldn't get it right.

Comment: @octnots best if you show what code you wrote so that we can help there. Sometimes it's just a "brain fart" and you were doing it right, other times you learn something fundamental that makes you so much better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.combinations`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
from itertools import combinations

for pair in combinations(combinations(l, 2), 2):
    # use pair
```

The first call creates the initial pairs:

```
>>> l = [0,1,2,3]
>>> list(combinations(l, 2))
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
```

The second pairs them again:

```
>>> list(combinations(combinations(l, 2), 2))
[((0, 1), (0, 2)), ((0, 1), (0, 3)), ((0, 1), (1, 2)), ((0, 1), (1, 3)), 
 ((0, 1), (2, 3)), ((0, 2), (0, 3)), ((0, 2), (1, 2)), ((0, 2), (1, 3)), 
 ((0, 2), (2, 3)), ((0, 3), (1, 2)), ((0, 3), (1, 3)), ((0, 3), (2, 3)), 
 ((1, 2), (1, 3)), ((1, 2), (2, 3)), ((1, 3), (2, 3))]
```

Comment: But this gives only `[(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]` and his question is a little different, I think

Comment: That gives all distinct pairs. I would like all (distinct) pairs of (distinct)  pairs.  But I can do ll = itertools.combinations(l,2). for pair in itertools.combinations(ll,2):   Thank you.